# How to define absolute positioned element's anchor point?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to define positioned element's anchor point without CSS transformations ?

I want to place an arrow before a variable centered div, but I have to define offset (left: -20px;).

If I were to increase the font size, the gap between the arrow and the block wouldn't be proportionate any more.

How can I define my absolute positioned element's anchor as top right corner instead of top left ?

HTML :

```
<div id="block">
   back
   <div id="arrow">&larr;</div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#block {
   height: 20px;
   width : 40px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   border: 1px solid black;
   position: relative;
}

#arrow {
   position: absolute;
   left: -20px;
   top : 0;
}
```

In this example the block is of fixed width, but in my code it is variable. Might need adiffrent solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/J7XnB/1/

Thank you !

Comment: To anchor off the right corner, just use `right: 150px` instead of `left: -20px` - this will position your element 150 px to the left of the right edge.

Comment: You can use 'em' instead of 'px': this will be based on font height instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using `em` as a unit of measurement, rather than absolute pixels:

```
#block {
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 1em;
    width: 2.5em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}

#arrow {
    position: absolute;
    left: -1em;
    top: 0;
}
```

Using `em` to measure the height and width of the `#block` also has the added advantage that if the font size is changed, then the box resizes to fit the text accordingly.

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/J7XnB/2/

(Just change the `font-size` property to see it change.)